# Is Google Analytics Tracking bi-directional?

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, google-analytics-4

Does anyone know if GA4 cross-domain tracking is bi-directional?

I have multiple sites (4+) that can all be in the same user journey. I have cross-domain tracking set up, but I would like to be able to see info from all the domains in one report. It seems like there will be many blindspots if the only way GA4 tracks it is if users start on the "main" site, but will not track if they come from email or direct from another source.

I have tried using the debug extention to see what events are passing to GA4, but it is only showing events from the main domain. The decorated URL is showing up, so I know the cookie info is passing from the main site to the linked domains.

Answer (score 0):

Depends. If it's one property, then yes, it's all-directional just make sure to include all domains affected.

If it's more than one property, then you have to set up cross-domain tracking in every GA4 property that lives on the domains affected. Domains that have properties missing the configuration will fail to pass their client ids to other domains.

Use an extension like Adswerve Data Layer Explorer. It will show the GA calls in the console. If you don't see these hits on the supplemental sites, then your cross domain tracking achieves nothing since they don't have analytics coverage.

In vast majority of usecases, the cross-domain tracking is set for the domains covered by the **same** GA property. Therefore, there's no need to include the domain list in more place than that one property.

Setting cross-domain tracking across different GA properties will still work, but the only feasible and real use case for doing it is when the data is then being ETLed from those properties into the same DB/table.